# Dog owner simulator

Tags: java, beginner, game

I've just started programming and read a book called *Head First Java*.

I thought it would be fun to make a training project that I can put all the stuff I learn into.  Is the code I've written here just really bad or good code written for a beginner?

I've got 4 classes:

#### Main class:

```
public class Main {
    Player p = new Player();
    p.Decision();
}
```

#### Player Class:

```
public class Player {

    int decision = 0;
    int exit = 1;
    int wd;

    int yesorno;

    boolean firstTimePlaying = true;

    Game g = new Game();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void Decision() {
        if (firstTimePlaying == true) {
            g.firstTime();
            firstTimePlaying = false;
        }

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Go out for a walk with your dog: 1 | Play with your dog: 2");
            decision = s.nextInt();
            if (decision == 1) {
                g.OutForAWalk();
            } else if (decision == 2) {
                g.play();
            } else if (decision == 425) {
                System.out.println("This is a developer option!");
                System.out.println("This will make you change your dogs name and size!");
                System.out.println("Do you wish to continue?");
                yesorno = s.nextInt();
                if (yesorno == 1)
                    g.firstTime();

            } else {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }

            System.out.println("Do you want to continue? Yes: 1 No: 2");
            exit = s.nextInt();
            if (exit > 1)
                break;
        }
    }
```

#### Game Class:

```
public class Game {
    int seeingAhydrant = 0;
    int wantingToPoop = 0;
    int seeingAnotherDog = 0;
    int fun = 0;
    String dogName;
    int size;

    Dog dog = new Dog();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int chooise = 1;

    public void firstTime() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to this dog owner sim game!");
        System.out.println("Please write the name of your new dog: ");
        dogName = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please write the size of your new dog: ");
        size = s.nextInt();
        dog.setName(dogName);
        dog.setSize(size);
        System.out.println("Now the game starts!");
    }

    public void OutForAWalk() {
        System.out.println("Player takes dog out for a walk");
        while (chooise < 2) {
            wantingToPoop += 2;
            seeingAhydrant = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
            seeingAnotherDog = (int) (Math.random() * 11);

            if (seeingAhydrant > 4) {
                dog.pee();
            } else if (wantingToPoop > 4) {
                dog.poop();
                wantingToPoop = 0;
            } else if (seeingAnotherDog > 7) {
                System.out.println("Suddenly another dog appear!");
                dog.bark();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Nothing special happend on thoose 100 meters");
            }
            System.out.println("Walk another 100 meters? 1 = yes/2 = no");
            chooise = s.nextInt();
        }
        chooise = 0;
    }

    // Bug inside play method, sometimes the dog dosen't show feelings (amuse, bored etc.)
    public void play() {
        while (chooise < 2) {
            System.out.println("You play with your dog.");
            fun = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
            if (fun < 1) {
                dog.verybored();
            } else if (fun > 0 && fun < 5) {
                dog.bored();
            } else if (fun > 4 && fun < 8) {
                dog.amused();
                dog.wiggleTail();
            } else if (fun > 7 && fun < 11) {
                dog.veryamused();
                dog.bark();
                dog.wiggleTail();
            }

            System.out.println("Do you want to play more with your dog? yes=1/no=2");
            chooise = s.nextInt();
        }
        chooise = 0;
    }
}
```

#### Dog Class:

```
public class Dog {

    private String name;
    private int size;

    public void bark() {
        if (size > 4)
            System.out.println(name + ": Woof Woof");
        else
            System.out.println(name + ": yip yip");
    }

    public void pee() {
        System.out.println(name + ": *Sees a hydrant* *peeing*");
    }

    public void poop() {
        System.out.println(name + ": *poops*");
    }

    public void wiggleTail() {
        System.out.println(name + ": *Wiggles tail*");
    }

    public void verybored() {
        System.out.println(name + ": *Looks really bored*");
    }

    public void bored() {
        System.out.println(name + ": *Looks bored*");
    }

    public void amused() {
        System.out.println(name + ": Looks amused");
    }

    public void veryamused() {
        System.out.println(name + ": Looks very amused");
    }

    //Getters and setters
    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(int s) {
        if (s < 1) {
            System.out.println("Size can't be less then one!");
            System.out.println("Setting size to one!");
            size = 1;
        } else if (s > 10) {
            System.out.println("Size can't be more then ten!");
            System.out.println("Setting size to ten!");
            size = 10;
        } else {
            size = s;
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String n) {
        name = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Stubbing in support for Easter Eggs already, I see!

Comment: Haha yeah i do ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Besides the comments you've already received, I'm adding some more:

---

Many of your variables can be marked as `private final`. **All** of them can be marked `private` and those who get initialized directly and never change should also be marked `final`. These include:

```
Game g = new Game();
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
```

---

Using `== true` is redundant here:

```
if (firstTimePlaying == true) {
```

It is enough with

```
if (firstTimePlaying) {
```

---

Some of your variable names are a bit too short and does not properly describe what they are used for:

```
int wd;
Game g
Scanner s
```

`g` can be called `game` and `s` either `scanner` or `input`. There's no need to use such short variable names, unless you are starting to run out of power in your keyboard (which I doubt).

In fact, your `wd` variable doesn't seem to be used at all. If it would have been marked as `private` your IDE would have told you about that.

---

It is a good practice to *always use braces*

```
if (yesorno == 1)
        g.firstTime();
```

is better written as:

```
if (yesorno == 1) {
    g.firstTime();
}
```

Many bugs have occurred in many programs because braces were missed.

---

You don't mention that you have to press `1` or `2` here. As a user, I would probably press `y`.

```
System.out.println("Do you wish to continue?");
yesorno = s.nextInt();
```

...Speaking of that, I would recommend that you change the functionality so that the user can input `y` or `n` instead. Entering 1 or 2 for yes/no is counter-intuitive. You want to make it simple for the user, even if it means it will be more complicated for you.

---

This error message describes absolutely nothing about what went wrong:

```
System.out.println("Error");
```

If I would encounter such a non-describing error I would have thought that something went totally wrong in your program.

State instead "You entered an incorrect value, please input either a, b or c...".

---

425 is a magic and seemingly random number. Magic numbers should not be entered in your code directly but instead used as named constants.

Instead, use this at the top of your class:

```
private static final int DEBUG_OPTION = 425;
```

And then in your code, use:

```
} else if (decision == DEBUG_OPTION) {
```

---

You have several methods that calls `System.out.println(name + ": ...");`

```
public void pee() {
    System.out.println(name + ": *Sees a hydrant* *peeing*");
}

public void poop() {
    System.out.println(name + ": *poops*");
}
```

I consider this as code duplication, what if you wanted to change `name + ": "` to `name + " says: "`? At the moment you would have to modify several lines for that. Your code will be a lot more maintainable, and slightly more readable if you *extract a method*:

```
private void perform(String action) {
    System.out.println(name + ": " + action);
}

public void pee() {
    perform("*Sees a hydrant* *peeing*");
}

public void poop() {
    perform("*poops*");
}

public void wiggleTail() {
    perform("*Wiggles tail*");
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer Simon! May i ask if you are from sweden? Your name sounds pretty swedish ^^

Comment: @Svante Indeed I am Swedish. Come and say Hej to me and the other (non-Swedish) site regulars in [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) chatroom :)

Answer (score 11):

There are a number of things to be improved, but here's a start:

1. Functions should be named according to what they do. This means they should often start with a verb, so rather than `Game.OutForAWalk()`, it should be `Game.goOutForAWalk()`. (There are exceptions. For example, when checking a condition, you can use `.is*`.) Furthermore, they should be named in `camelCase`; the first letter should be lowercase, while the first letter in each word should be uppercase.
2. Consider aggregating your dog mood functions into a single `Dog.printMood()` method. You'll probably soon learn about `enum`s; an enum would be a natural way to store and represent the dog's current mood (à la `Dog.setMood(Dog.MOOD.HAPPY)`).
3. If you're looking for a 40% chance of something, then `Math.random() < 0.4` or `(int)(Math.random() * 10) < 4` will do what you want. `fun = (int)(Math.random() * 11)` will get you a random number from `0` to `10` inclusive, so `fun < 4` will actually be a 36% chance.
4. Your `if` chain is needlessly complex. Remember that an `else if` will only be considered if all preceding `if`s and `else if`s failed. Thus, you can instead use an `if`-`else` ladder similar to the following. (Note that the percentages are accurate only if you change your `random` line to use `10` rather than `11`.

   ```
   if (fun < 1)      // 10% chance: 0
   else if (fun < 5) // 40% chance: 1, 2, 3, 4
   else if (fun < 8) // 30% chance: 5, 6, 7
   else              // 20% chance: 8, 9
   ```
5. A condition like `seeingAHydrant > 4` makes no sense. Consider changing changing that to:

   ```
   boolean seesAHydrant = Math.random() < 0.6; // 60% chance
   if (seesAHydrant) {
       ...
   }
   ```
6. `chooise` should be either `choice` or `choose`. In this case, `choice` makes more sense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will look into the things you wrote and try to change my code! :)

Comment: @Svante: Just don't change the code you've posted, please.  It must stay intact after answers have been posted.

Comment: @Jamal No, i meant the code i have in my IDE.

Comment: @Svante: Okay, just making sure.

Comment: *"(Note that the percentages are accurate only if you change your "* your what?

Comment: @Simon Thanks. I started writing that line and then moved somewhere else.